# nodejs connection fail to database

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i'm trying to build a simple rest api based on node.js + mongodb
i'm using https://cloud.mongodb.com/ and my connection string is 1000% correct 
i keep having this problem sometimes it work for me all the day no issue 
and sometimes it doesn't wanna connect and i changed nothing in the code
anyone is having similar issues?

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
require('dotenv/config');

app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Import routes
const postsRoute = require('./routes/posts');
app.use('/posts', postsRoute);

//mongodb connect
mongoose.connect(process.env.db_access, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true },
() => {
    console.log('connected');
}
);

//ROUTES
app.get('/', (req,res) => {
 res.send('home boi');
});


//listening port
app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Can you connect over the command line/Compass (or just ping it)?

Comment: got a problem with string connection too  ! do u recommand me any other free hosting mongodb platform?

Comment: It looks like the problem is a connection issue, I would recommend running MongoDB locally and trying until you can run the code with a stable connection.